# Unit name в Delphi

Tags: delphi, msbuild

При создании проекта в Delphi 10.1 Berlin возникает ошибка "Cannot resolve unit name...". Подчёркивает красным следующие uses: Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs; и TForm. Все пакеты в Install Packages добавлены

Первые 10 строк модуля:

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,

Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
```

[image: Сообщение компилятора]

Ошибка компилятора:

> Checking project dependencies...
>   Compiling Project1.dproj (Debug, Win32)
>
> [Error Error] Invalid PLATFORM variable "MCD". PLATFORM must be one of the following: "Win32", "Win64", "Android", "iOSSimulator", "iOSDevice32" "iOSDevice64", or "OSX32". If PLATFORM is defined by your system's environment, it must be overridden in the RAD Studio IDE or passed explicitly on the command line to MSBuild; e.g., /p:Platform=Win32.
>
> Failed
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0

Comment: Проект компилируется?

Comment: Нет, он пишет, что даже TForm не объявлена

Comment: Приведите точное сообщение компилятора. А также покажите первые 10 строк этого модуля

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Я попросил ошибки **компилятора**. Т.е. те ошибки, которые появляются при нажатии Ctrl+F9

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: У Вас в системных переменных Windows не объявлена ли переменная `PLATFORM`?

Comment: Что это и где это посмотреть?

Comment: Мой компьютер - Свойства - Дополнительные параметры системы - Переменные среды

Comment: Удалил, теперь всё работает. Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, что это за переменная и почему её нужно было удалить?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795530/error-invalid-platform-variable-mcd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Компиляция проекта производится при помощи утилиты MSBuild. Эта утилита использует переменную `PLATFORM` для определения целевой платформы компиляции. Возможные значения этой переменной для сборки Delphi проекта "Win32", "Win64", "Android", "iOSSimulator", "iOSDevice32" "iOSDevice64", "OSX32".

Значение этой переменной можно задать в IDE (Tools - Options - Environment options). Если оно не задано в IDE, то эта переменная ищется в переменных среды. Если не найдена, то подставляется, собственно, целевая платформа компиляции.

У Вас эта переменная нашлась в системных. И ее значение (MCD) оказалось невалидным для сборки Delphi проекта.

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Переопределить ее в IDE
2. Удалить из системных переменных